# Buggy blink effect with CSS multiple transition when use 'all' property

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a problem with the CSS `transition` property.
I need to declare two transitions for a `section`-tag. Every transition with the section should have a duration of 1s, only the background should have a duration of 0.3s

So my CSS-`transition` code would look like that:

```
section{
   background: black;
   transition: all 1s ease, background 0.3s ease;
}
section:hover{
   background: green;
   transform: translateY(100px);
}
```

But when I hovering the link now, the background get animated in 1s and it blinks strangely.
[Here the codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/maxwbailey/pen/iAHxa)

Someone know why this happend? And how can I realize my goal?
And yes, I need the `all` property!

### EDIT

Just found a strange one. In the linked codepen above, it blinks. But when I animate also the `padding`, it stop blinking! But the background will be animated in 1s...
[Here's the second demo](http://codepen.io/maxwbailey/pen/DdrAH)

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this in code pen, the problem not in the transition property.

Better you use **div tag** for the link background and create separate transition for that.

Surely div tag will give the best solution for your problem.

Comment: `+1`, for links etc. it works. It's my mistake, on my site it isn't a link, it is a section tag. I edited my question...

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurred because **as you hover over the element, it starts moving downwards.**
When the element is **not hovered, it would revert back.**
Now as you hover, the elements starts moving and then **loses the hover immediately** which causes it to **return to original state but again gains the hover effect** as it again receives the mouse-over event which also **cause blink, and the strange phenomenon** you observed.
If you place mouse close towards the bottom, you observe the desired effect.

The fix should be that you write a hover for the container that contains these elements and apply the effect to these elements.

Besides you've applied transition in only 1 state which also may be the reason for blink;

try using transitions to both the statements like below:

```
section{

  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:black;
  color:white;
  transition: background 0.3s ease, all 3s ease;
}
section:hover{
  background:green;
  transition: background 0.3s ease, all 3s ease;
}
```

Comment: It also blinks when I delete the transform statement... Look now at the codepen.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. But when I copy the transition in the `:hover` area, it doesn't change anything...

Comment: it does in some specified time